# Open subset of Topological Space

Tags: general-topology

If I have some topological space $X$ with topology $\mathcal{T}$, is any open subset of $X$ a topological space with the same topology.

I'm just starting to teach myself about topological spaces. After looking at the open set and neighborhood definition I was wondering if this is true. I feel like it is but I'm not sure how to justify that. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper open set $U$ cannot be a topological space with the *same* topology $\mathcal T$. This is because $\mathcal T$ has $X$ in it, while $X$ is not a subset if $U$.

However, given *any* subset $A$ of $X$, you can construct a topology $\mathcal T_A$ on $A$ by defining $\mathcal T_A$ as
$$\mathcal T_A = \{U\cap A:\ U\in \mathcal T\}$$

It is a trivial check that $\mathcal T_A$ is indeed a topology on $A$.

This is called the **subspace topology** induced on $A$ by $X$.

Comment: Note that, because $U$ is itself open, $\mathcal{T}_U=\{O \in \mathcal{T}: O \subseteq U\}= \mathscr{P}(U) \cap \mathcal{T}$.

Answer (score 1):

It can't necessarily be a topological space with the *same* topology, right?  Unless the subset you're considering is $X$ itself.

But what you can do, is consider the *subspace topology*.  The open sets are defined to be intersections of open sets in $\tau$ with $\mathscr U$.